# how to fix ValueError: None is only supported in the 1st dimension

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I am now trying to convert my `savedmodel` to `tflite` format. 
while doing that, I got the following error message.

> ValueError: None is only supported in the 1st dimension

I guess this issue is mainly due to a part of my source code:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None, None], name='JW_Input')
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([28, 28, 10]))
```

Actually, it is difficult to change my original codes regarding input shape since I have to consider various size of input image.

Is there another solution to fix this issue?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import shutil

input_array = np.zeros((1, 28, 28))

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None, None], name='JW_Input')
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([28, 28, 10]))
y = tf.matmul(x, W, name='JW_Output')

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: input_array})

    target_dir = 'savedmodel_test_dir'
    if os.path.isdir(target_dir) is True:
        shutil.rmtree(target_dir)

    tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess, 'savedmodel_test_dir', inputs={'Input': x}, outputs={'Output': y})

src_model_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "savedmodel_test_dir")
convert = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(src_model_file,
                                                   input_arrays=["JW_Input"],
                                                   output_arrays=["JW_Output"])
convert.convert()
```

The expected result: no error while converting.

The actual result: error happens with the following message.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't have TFLite models with a variable input size. Even the first dimension has to be fixed. Although the error says that 'None' is ok if it's in the first dimension, in reality you'll hit other errors during inference if you have 'None' in ANY dimension of your input.

The reason for that is that TFLite converter performs multiple graph transformations to optimize your graph, and these transformations need to be able to propagate (fixed) sizes for all tensors in the graph.

This is the case for TF at least up to version 1.14